# Does the New Testament say that Christians should read the Bible every day?

Tags: biblical-basis, bible-reading

I would like to know whether the Bible says that Christians should read the Bible every day.

In the old testament, I have found some verses which say that Jews should read the Law every day. For example Psalms 1:2 and Psalms 119:97.

However, some things have changed when the new testament came. For example, circumcision is not a commandment for Christians (Galations 5:2). But some commandments from the Law still hold for all Christians, such as the command to abstain from sexual immorality (Acts 15:20).

Therefore, I would like to know if there is a verse inside the New Testament, which applies to all Christians and which explicitly says that we should read the Bible every single day?

EDIT: since the word 'Bible' does not occur in the Bible, a synonym would also suffice.

Comment: it won't explicitly say the bible because the bible was put together after the fact. would a verse about scripture be enough or are you looking for the word bible?

Comment: The Bible doesn't assume everyone can read, but it does want all Christians to be in Bible-saturated Christian communities. Reading and hearing together is arguably much more important than reading alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many years after Jesus' death and resurrection, the only holy scriptures Christians had were the Hebrew scriptures (what came to be called 'The Old Testament'). Even once the apostles and others began to write about Christ and the growth of the new Christian Church, it took a while for enough copies to be hand-written to spread throughout all the expanding congregations of believers in Jesus. Those 27 documents were only completed around A.D.95 (with the last writing, Revelation).

That is the simple, and logical, reason why you do not read any command in what has come to be called 'The New Testament' to read the Old and New Testament scriptures every day. There might have been scope to instruct daily reading of the Old Testament for those who could get into a synagogue or the temple every day, for that was where the scrolls of parchment were kept. A very few rich individuals might have had private copies. Also, given that not everybody could read back then, a requirement for all Christian to do daily reading would be unreasonable. Think, too, of the many people whose eye-sight would be too poor to read - and no glasses were available then!

Even in the nation of Israel, before Christ, only a few would be able to read the Hebrew scriptures every day. The king was commanded to do that. But the two verses you cite speak about daily meditation of God's law. That does not actually require daily reading of the law. One can read, then meditate on the reading after they've put the scroll back and they go about their daily or weekly business. Even at night, king David spoke about not being able to sleep and meditating on that law, and he also sang psalms of praise (and composed them), with those psalms then being added to the scriptures later on. Again, the scrolls of scriptures were copied and held by well educated scribes. The custom was for people to gather and have someone read parts of them out aloud, publicly. They could not gather every day, especially not the majority who lived scattered throughout the countryside!

Yet the power and worth of those hand-written manuscripts was well known amongst God's people, and children were taught to read and to write, and to have scripture instruction in school. A huge emphasis was laid on children memorising great chunks of the scriptures - precisely because few would have access to written copies in later life. The modern mind, however, needs to adjust to the fact that books were not yet invented, and scrolls had to be kept safely in places like synagogues or the temple.

Once the last book of what later became known as The Bible was written, it is significant that it records Jesus as saying, "Blessed is he that keepeth the sayings of this prophecy of this book." It also speaks of ***hearing*** the words of that scroll:

> "For I testify unto every man that heareth the words of the prophecy
> of this book, If any man shall add unto these things, God shall add
> unto  him the plagues that are written in this book. And if any man
> shall take away from the words of the book of this prophecy, God shall
> take away his part out of the book of life, and out of the holy city,
> and from the things which are written in this book." (Rev. 22:7 &
> 18-19)

We know from what was written about Jesus that he taught followers how the Hebrew scriptures were fulfilled in him. Then, on the road to Emmaus, he said to the two believers,

> "O fools, and slow of heart to believe all that the prophets have
> spoken [in the O.T.]. Ought not Christ to have suffered these things,
> and to enter into his glory." And beginning at Moses and all the
> prophets, he expounded unto them in all the scriptures the things
> concerning himself." Luke 24:25-27

You can be sure that those enlightened disciples would make every effort to then get reading the O.T. texts Jesus had explained to them. And when, years later, the N.T. accounts were written, they would be avidly read by all who could do that. They wouldn't be able to get enough of them! Nobody would need to command them to read every day! They would, if they could.

It is tragic that, today, when the scriptures are available in thousands of languages, in print and on-line, that there is an awful dearth of reading them. There probably is more ignorance of the scriptures now than at any other time after the Reformation. People are so easily distracted with what their eyes see and what their ears hear - they are so busy working, playing, going on holiday, shopping... a hundred and one excuses can be made. But those who love their Lord soak up the scriptures at every opportunity, not as a duty or obligation - but because they love the Lord, and the scriptures are all about their precious Lord.

**Christians do not need to be told what they ***should*** do.** They know what to do to please their Lord because they know his words and the value of the scriptures.

Comment: Good point! If most people did not have the ability to read the scriptures, then it is logical that they were not instructed to do that

Answer (score 3):

The very term 'disciple' suggests that followers of Jesus Christ will be organised and sensible and disciplined ; and therefore will be fruitful - useful and productive.

Paul says of Timothy that 'from a child' he had known the scriptures of the time :

> And that from a child thou hast known the holy scriptures, which are able to make thee wise unto salvation through faith which is in Christ Jesus. [2 Timothy 3:15-17],

and this was no doubt due to the influence of his mother Eunice and his grandmother Lois, 2 Timothy 1:5.

Notably, Paul writes that these holy scriptures are able to make wise unto salvation and this is the point, given that we wish to be saved.

We have been given an existence, given life, given humanity ; and we live in a world which has been visited by 'God manifest in flesh', 1 Timothy 3:16.

What else shall we do with our time, but be disciplined, diligent, for our own sakes, that we might be wise unto our own salvation ?

I cannot think of any scripture that, specifically, tells us to read the bible every day. Even when the disciples asked Jesus about prayer, he said 'when ye pray' making it voluntary, not compulsory, as to the exact timing and duration of the activity.

The same for baptism, it is voluntary : but necessary if one wishes to meet with others in a public way.

The same for giving. It is voluntary, but none will prosper who hordes their wealth and is not generous ; they will clearly be miserly and miserable persons.

We are given everything, in scripture - full revelation, progressively, from ancient times until the coming of Christ, and then the epistles and then the visions of John.

What a wealth ! What a privilege !

Why would we not want to read it every day, and store it up in our minds and meditate upon it always ? Why would we not ?

> ... they received the word with all readiness of mind, and searched the scriptures **daily**... Acts 17:11 KJV.

---

It goes without saying that some are unable to read, or find it difficult, or have not the full capacity to be able to assimilate. 'Comfort the feeble-minded, support the weak' says the scripture.

And reading aloud is hugely edifying, I have always found, for both the reader and the hearers.

Comment: Reasons why someone would not every day read in the Bible: 1. Maybe there are periods that someone is fully busy with doing what is written in the Bible. 2. Maybe there are periods when one is not motivated to read in the Bible, for example following a period of intensive Bible study 3. There may be periods that one is just very busy and then it is ok to don't read in the Bible for some time. 4. You can view the Bible as a very important book, and read it from beginning to end. Then lay it aside for a number of months or years, and after that read it again from beginning to end

Comment: @Riemann I do not recommend 'lay it aside for a number of months or years'. That does not seem, to me, to be the actions of someone intent on being saved (in my own opinion). Unless one's mind is full of the word of God, worldliness and carnality will flood in and overcome. We are in a battle and a war (if we wish to be saved). 'Fight the good fight.' 'Lay hold on eternal life'.

Comment: Personally I am every day involved in 'spiritual stuff' like fighting against sin and praying and trying to live a good life. Therefore, I stay focused on God's way of life.

Comment: The overcoming of sin is through faith in Christ. And 'faith cometh by hearing' (the word of God). And when the Bereans heard 'they searched the scriptures -daily- whether these things were so'.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the New Testament texts that say we should study the scriptures:

> John 5:39 Search the scriptures; for in them ye think ye have eternal life: and they are they which testify of me.

Paul said:

> 2Tim 2:15 Study to shew thyself approved unto God, a workman that needeth not to be ashamed, rightly dividing the word of truth.

Paul commissioned the believers to think on certain things:

> Phil 4:8 Finally, brethren, whatsoever things are true, whatsoever things are honest, whatsoever things are just, whatsoever things are pure, whatsoever things are lovely, whatsoever things are of good report; if there be any virtue, and if there be any praise, think on these things.
> Phil 4:9 Those things, which ye have both learned, and received, and heard, and seen in me, do: and the God of peace shall be with you.

We find in the old testament, that the scriptures alone fully matches with the above criteria:

> Ps 19:7 The law of the LORD is perfect, converting the soul: the testimony of the LORD is sure, making wise the simple.
> Ps 19:8 The statutes of the LORD are right, rejoicing the heart: the commandment of the LORD is pure, enlightening the eyes.
> Ps 19:9 The fear of the LORD is clean, enduring for ever: the judgments of the LORD are true and righteous altogether.
> Ps 19:10 More to be desired are they than gold, yea, than much fine gold: sweeter also than honey and the honeycomb.
> Ps 19:11 Moreover by them is thy servant warned: and in keeping of them there is great reward.

Paul said we should think on these things - meaning we should constantly dwell on these things, for what we behold that we become.

Peter said we need to consume the scriptures to grow. Growth is a continuous process and the nutrients should be consistently supplied if one desires continuous growth.

> 1Pet 2:2 As newborn babes, desire the sincere milk of the word, that ye may grow thereby:

James said that the word of God is able to save our souls:

> Jas 1:21 Wherefore lay apart all filthiness and superfluity of naughtiness, and receive with meekness the engrafted word, which is able to save your souls.

Further he explains,

> Jas 1:22 But be ye doers of the word, and not hearers only, deceiving your own selves.
> Jas 1:23 For if any be a hearer of the word, and not a doer, he is like unto a man beholding his natural face in a glass:
> Jas 1:24 For he beholdeth himself, and goeth his way, and straightway forgetteth what manner of man he was.
> Jas 1:25 But whoso looketh into the perfect law of liberty, and continueth therein, he being not a forgetful hearer, but a doer of the work, this man shall be blessed in his deed.

We can see:

1. one beholding glass and going away is like an occasional reader of the word - he does not continue in it
2. one who continues in the word - he is a doer and he keeps looking into the glass i.e. the Law of God and the word of God.

Paul also said:

> 2Cor 3:18 But we all, with open face beholding as in a glass the glory of the Lord, are changed into the same image from glory to glory, even as by the Spirit of the Lord.

As we behold Christ through the Word of God, we become changed into the same image from glory to glory - meaning as we keep looking we discern more and more of God's character and keep changing. The converse being if we stop looking, we stop changing and the natural inclinations will take hold and we become changed into the image of the enemy.

So even though the New Testament does not explicitly say we should study the scriptures everyday, it abounds with the implicit instruction "Study the scriptures everyday and meditate on it continuously"

A blessing is pronounced on the reader:

> Rev 22:7 Behold, I come quickly: blessed is he that keepeth the sayings of the prophecy of this book.

Though specifically talking about Revelation, this holds true for all the Scriptures.

> Rev 1:3 Blessed is he that readeth, and they that hear the words of this prophecy, and keep those things which are written therein: for the time is at hand.

Comment: It seems like some of these verses have the message that we should do what is written in the word; i.e. don't sin, love our neighbours, etc. and that that is much more important than reading the word.

Comment: About Philippians 4:8: does making a walk in nature, or enjoying delicious food made by God not satisfy these criteria?

Comment: These things do satisfy the criteria, but if a list is made of all the things that satisfy the criteria, the Word of God tops it. There can nothing be more perfect  than the word of God, the life of Christ and the Law of God

Comment: For example, do we find imperfections in the nature? Yes, because of sin. But the Bible says the Law of the Lord is perfect.

Comment: To not love sin, to love our neighbors - this does not come automatically to sinful human beings. "Behold the lamb of God" - this is the only way to be born again. Jesus said when I am lifted up from the earth, I will draw all men unto me. The savior has to be lifted up. How are we to behold? There is no other source to behold the life of Christ other than the word of God. That is why, when talking about the righteous, the old testament says "In His law doth he meditate day and night"